# Check if attribute is wrap_content or fixed height (Programatically)

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to check whether a `View` subclass had `wrap_content` or a fixed value on its `android:layout_height` property from a `ListView`'s `Adapter`, how can I do this programatically?

PS: it is in order to do something like this:

```
// Pseudo code
If attribute = wrap_content Then
    calculateViewHeight();
Else 
    // If it was fixed, do nothing
End if
```

And nope, **I can't** `Override` `onMeasure()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
if(lp.height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
    //do something
} else {
    //fixed height.
}
```

Comment: lp.height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT